# table responsive does not work in IOS browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I create table with bootstrap. this table in android browsers scroll works without problems but in ios browsers scroll does not work.what's wrong?

Comment: Can you share a link/codepen so that we can help?

Comment: this is my code : 
                    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="list">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>#</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>